# Ignore Query String

Tags: .htaccess, query-string

I have a website which supplies free wallpapers and from some reason when people try to get to it using google images, the link becomes broken...

**Example**

*OK*

```
http://www.hdwallfree.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/bugatti_venom_concept_silver_car_wallpaper-1440x900.jpg
```

*BAD*

```
http://www.hdwallfree.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/bugatti_venom_concept_silver_car_wallpaper-1440x900.jpg&ei=etRQVL66L4ePPfjqgPAF&bvm=bv.78597519,d.bGQ&psig=AFQjCNFhKbHEllHuv7ebxSATTR9udy2FQA&ust=1414669809124608
```

Pay attention thats google images adds query strings that makes my site no work properly...

So my question is, how can i make WordPress ignore those query strings?

*The full .htaccess:* http://pastebin.com/kHNL5DQi

Answer (score 0):

In your main wordpress .htaccess you can insert this redirect rule **just below `RewriteBase` line**:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

This will **strip unwanted query string** from image URLs.

Comment: It is a tested and working rule. Where is your .htaccess located? Is there any .htaccess inside `/wp-content/` OR `/wp-content/uploads/` fodlers?

Comment: no, only in the main folder `public_html`... see the full htaccess file

Comment: I checked your .htaccess, you need to move this rule just below first `RewriteEngine` line below line # 29

Comment: still not working... that bizarre, i can see that the query string doesn't start with a question mark, is there something else?

Comment: That's weird, try placing it in `/wp-content/uploads/.htaccess` below `RewriteEngine On` line.